# how to check memory allocated to tomcat on linux server

Tags: linux, tomcat, memory, server, response

We are facing server responding slow issue for tomcat servers.

How to check memory allocated to tomcat on Linux server? I tried in shell

```
ps -aux| grep tomcat and netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

But no luck.

Comment: Also CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS  in catalina.sh file.

Comment: Use `top` command and look after your process/service for memory.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

`top -p <PID of your tomcat>` command will give resource utilization of only tomcat's.